# Animation noise help

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, lighting

is there any way to decrease the amount of noise? It is an animation and I want the best results possible. Blender denoiser causes flickering so I want to use denoiser in Davinci. But still I need to cut down the noise. This is rendered at 14K samples.

Thank you in advance[image]

Comment: which engine are you using ?

Comment: I use Cycles in Blender